# Selecting rows with the most repeated values at specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sql-order-by, inner-join

Problem in general words: I need to select value from one table referenced to the most repeated values in another table.

Tables have this structure:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rymt.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jml9G.png)

The question is to find country which has the most results from sportsmen related to it.

First, INNER JOIN tables to have relation between result and country

```
SELECT competition_id, country FROM result
INNER JOIN sportsman USING (sportsman_id);
```

Then, I count how much time each country appear

```
SELECT country, COUNT(country) AS highest_participation
FROM (SELECT competition_id, country FROM result
    INNER JOIN sportsman USING (sportsman_id))
GROUP BY country
;
```

And got this [screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbeXf.png)

Now it feels like I'm one step away from solution ))
**I guess it's possible with one more SELECT FROM (SELECT ...) and MAX() but I can't wrap it up?**

ps:
I did it with doubling the query like this but I feel like it's so inefficient if there are millions of rows.

```
SELECT country 
    FROM (SELECT country, COUNT(country) AS highest_participation
        FROM (SELECT competition_id, country FROM result 
            INNER JOIN sportsman USING (sportsman_id) 
            ) GROUP BY country 
        ) 
WHERE highest_participation = (SELECT MAX(highest_participation)  
    FROM (SELECT country, COUNT(country) AS highest_participation
        FROM (SELECT competition_id, country FROM result 
            INNER JOIN sportsman USING (sportsman_id) 
            ) GROUP BY country 
        ))
```

Also I did it with a view

```
CREATE VIEW temp AS 
    SELECT country as country_with_most_participations, COUNT(country) as country_participate_in_#_comp 
    FROM( 
        SELECT country, competition_id FROM result 
        INNER JOIN sportsman USING(sportsman_id)
        ) 
    GROUP BY country;
SELECT country_with_most_participations FROM temp 
WHERE country_participate_in_#_comp = (SELECT MAX(country_participate_in_#_comp) FROM temp);
```

But not sure if it's easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you want to rank the countries per competition count and show the highest ranking country (or countries) with their count. I suggest you use `RANK` for the ranking.

```
select country, competition_count
from
(
  select 
    s.country,
    count(*) as competition_count,
    rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn
  from sportsman s
  inner join result r using (sportsman_id)
  group by s.country
) ranked_by_count
where rn = 1
order by country;
```

If the order of the result rows doesn't matter, you can shorten this to:

```
select s.country, count(*) as competition_count      
from sportsman s
inner join result r using (sportsman_id)
group by s.country
order by count(*) desc
fetch first rows with ties;
```

Comment: Thank you. Second query is exactly what I was looking for. 
"fetch first rows with ties" seems to be really useful when there is possibly more than one highest value.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be overcomplicating this. Starting from your existing `join` query, you can aggregate, order the results and keep the top row(s) only.

```
select s.country, count(*) cnt
from sportsman s
inner join result r using (sportsman_id)
group by s.country
order by cnt desc
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

Note that this allows top ties, if any.

Comment: I guess you mean INNER not cross. Otherwise this is it. ty

Comment: @void_eater: sure. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country 
    FROM (SELECT country, COUNT(country) AS highest_participation
        FROM (SELECT competition_id, country FROM result 
            INNER JOIN sportsman USING (sportsman_id) 
            ) GROUP BY country 
order by 2 desc
        ) 
where rownum=1
```

Comment: Will miss values if there are more than one MAX